# rails ajax internationalization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, localization, internationalization

I'm working on localizing my rails web application and have gotten the static part of the page to localize correctly.  However, there is a partial that is reloaded through asynchronously and doesn't localize correctly.  The partial will randomly choose one of the three languages that I've set and reloads with that instead of staying uniform with the localization of the static part of the page.  Any help would be appreciated. Here is my application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_locale


  private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] #|| I18n.default_locale #**WHEN  I UNCOMMENT THIS IT MAKES IT SO THAT IT AUTOMATICALLY USES THE DEFAULT THAT I SET REGARDLESS OF THE LOCALIZATION IT SHOULD BE ON**
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
end
```

This is the config/application file:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :zhtw, :zhcn]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :zhtw
  end
```

This is the section of routes where it has the scope:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/  do
    get 'vocabs/choosezh' => 'vocabs#choosezh'
    post 'vocabs/choosezh' => 'vocabs#choosezh'
    I18n.load_path
  end
```

This is the js.erb file for the partial _vocab:

```
$('#vocab').html("<%= j (render 'vocabs/vocab.html') %>");
```

This is the anchor code in the html.erb file:

```
<div id = "vocab">
  <%= render 'vocab' %>
</div>
```

This is the part of the controller action where the ajax is handled:

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render(:text => "not implemented") }
        format.js { render partial: 'vocabs/vocab' }
      end
```

This is the html.erb document form that triggers the AJAX upon submission:

```
<div id="main" align = "center">
  <%= form_tag vocabs_start_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: "selection_form" do %>
    <%= select_tag :level, options_for_select([[ "#{t :level1}", 0], [ "#{t :level2}", 1], [ "#{t :level3}", 2], [ "#{t :level4}", 3]])%>
    <%= label_tag(:q, "#{t :select_form}") %>
    <%= select_tag :selection, options_for_select([["#{t :nonpast}", 1], ["#{t :plainpast}", 2], ["#{t :teform}", 3], ["#{t :iform}", 4], ["#{t :ifs}", 5], ["#{t :potential}", 6], ["#{t :passive}", 7], ["#{t :causative}", 8], ["#{t :causativepassive}", 9], ["#{t :volitionals}", 10], ["#{t :conjecturals}", 11], ["#{t :alternatives}", 12], ["#{t :imperatives}", 13], ["#{t :honorific}", 14]])   %>
  <%= submit_tag("#{t :start}", id: "submit") %>
  <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
    <div>
      <%= text_field_tag :answer, params[:vocab], placeholder: "#{t :input}", autofocus: true, class: "form-control search-box input-lg", :onkeypress => 'check()', disable_with: 'Saving...' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= button_tag(type: :button, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success", :onclick => "check()") do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <%= t :check %>
        </div>
    <br /><br />
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id = "selectiontable">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h1><%= t :clickverblist %> </h1>
    <table>
      <% @vocabs.each_slice(10) do |vocabs| %>
    <tr>


      <% vocabs.each do |vocab| %>
          <td><label class = "checkbox">
          <%= check_box_tag(":choice_id[]", value = vocab.id, checked = false)%><%= vocab.casual %><% end %> </label></td>

    <% end %>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag("#{t :chooseverbs}", id: "submit") %>
    </div>
    </div>
      <% end %>

<% end %>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add ajax code as well (if it is form/anchor them form/anchor, if other ajax then form/anchor along with ajax code)

Comment: I edited it to include Ajax.

Comment: Please include code that trigger ajax not handling of ajax.

Comment: The ajax is triggered by the submission of this form, I have included it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add hidden field in the form for

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :locale, params[:locale] %>
```

It will resolve your problem and also add this line by removing comment sign

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
```

PS: Please store this within db and use it with current user something like

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || current_user&.locale || I18n.default_locale
```

The reason for doing this is you won't have to send locale for every request (on links and on forms).